# Communication between Java programs

Tags: java, networking

I'm trying to learn how to do deal with networks in Java 8, and I'm trying to make a client program communicate with a server one. The client is asked a string, which is sent to the server, and the server sends it back in upper characters.

I can't get my server part to work, it simply won't write anything except the fact that the connection is made. Could someone explain what's wrong with my code ?

Server :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int listenPort = 9000;
    ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(listenPort);
    Socket socket = listenSocket.accept();

    System.out.println("Connexion réussie !");

    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

    String line = null;

    System.out.println("test : " + buffer.readLine());

    while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Message reçu : " + line);
        System.out.println("Message envoyé : " + line.toUpperCase());
        output.writeUTF(line.toUpperCase());

        if(line.equals("stop")) {
            socket.close();
            listenSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client side :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9000);

    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String line = null;

    while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Message envoyé : " + line);
        output.writeChars(line);
        System.out.println("Message reçu : " + input.readUTF());

        if(line.equals("stop")) {
            break;
        }
    }

    socket.close();

}
```

Comment: try adding a `output.flush()` right after `output.writeChars()`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your client method, you call `output.writeChars(line)` inside the while loop, this means that you send something to the server **after** the server send something to you.

Change your client code as follows:

```
String line = "What a wonderful line";
System.out.println("Message envoyé : " + line);
output.writeChars(line);

while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Message reçu : " + input.readUTF());
}
```